# SwiftUI - Why does GeometryReader cause .frame() modifier not to work?

Tags: swift, geometry, frame, swiftui

Here's the View code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Color.blue
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>[image: expected-result]
Expected Result</kbd> <kbd>[image: actual-result]
Actual Result</kbd>

My understanding of the layout process in this situation is as follows:

1. Full screen size is offered to the top level view, which is the `GeometryReader`.
2. `GeometryReader` accepts full offer.
3. `GeometryReader` goes on to offer its full size to the next view down, which in this case is the frame modifier of type `_ModifiedContent<Color, _FrameLayout>`.
4. Frame modifier ignores the offered size and declares that its size is 50x50, and is then positioned in the center of the `GeometryReader`.
5. Frame modifier offers its full size (50x50) to its child, `Color.blue`.
6. `Color.blue` passively accepts what it is offered and therefore also declares itself to be 50x50.

Therefore, the blue square should only be 50x50. I understand that the *GeometryReader* takes up the whole screen (I could put a border around it to verify), but the blue should be only filling the frame which surrounds it, which is 50x50 positioned in the middle of the `GeometryReader`. What am I missing? Or perhaps this is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the answer is that it was a bug. I updated to Xcode 11 Beta 5 and it now behaves as I expected.